# Как хранить состояния в таблице Q при обучении с подкреплением Q-learning?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, обучение-с-подкреплением

Для модели обучения с подкреплением есть таблица Q из n_states (число состояний) строк и n_action (число действий) столбцов.
Как я поняла, выбор действия происходит следующим образом:

```
epsilon = 0.9 # шанс выбрать случайное действие

# Выбираем случайное действие, пока неопределенность велика (таблица мало заполнена)
if np.random.uniform(0, 1) < epsilon: 
    action = ... # случайное действие
else:
    action = np.argmax(Q[state, :]) # лучшее действие, выбранное по таблице Q из строки текущего состояния
```

Если  состояние представлено не числом, а вектором, нужно ли создать словарь состояний и их индексов и хранить в Q индекс состояния?

Например, состояние 1 : [0, 0, 1, 0.3] и в таблице Q строка под номером 1 соответствует этому состоянию.
Аналогично с действиями.

Если состояний достаточно много (10^8), такой метод подойдет? Если нет, то как правильно это организовать?

Comment: Может вам лучше рассмотреть обучение нейронных сетей с использованием Q обучения потому что 10^8 состояний на 4 действия уже занимает где-то 3 гб оперативной памяти?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду метод" глубокое обучение с подкреплением", верно?

Comment: Да `глубокое обучение с подкреплением`